# What is the difference between these statements

Tags: c++

I have these two statements. What is the difference between 
`string(sample_string).erase(i,j)` 
and 
`sample_string.erase(i,j)` ?

Comment: did you try to see the difference ?

Comment: yes, I have this statement in for loop and without "string" at the beginning it doesnt work right and I dont know why

Comment: What is the type of `sample_string` ?

Comment: its also a string inside the bracket

Comment: "doesnt work" is a bit vague. If you tried it, you should tell us what difference you observed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sample_string.erase(i,j)
> ```

Calls the `erase` method on the `sample_string` object (assuming that this is an instance of a class that implements this method).

---

> ```
> string(sample_string).erase(i,j)
> ```

Creates a *temporary* instance of the `string` class, calling a `string` constructor using the `sample_string` object for initialization of the string, and then calls the `erase` method on that temporary object.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the type of simple_string is std::string. the code

```
string(sample_string).erase(i, j)
```

looked cannot work because string(sample_string) returns a temp obj, and then called erase method on the temporary string object. There is nothing to do with sample_string.

Comment: could be that he does `string new_string = string(sample_string).erase(i,j)` and further needs to use both `new_string` and `sample_string`

Comment: @vib, of course you can

Answer (score 0):

The first one, `string(sample_string).erase(i,j)` creates a *temporary* string, and erases from that temporary string.

The second erases from the string object `sample_string`.